# To overlay a button over the camera preview while scanning barcode in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I am using barcode scanner plugin in my phonegap project. That plugin works fine. In my HTML page i have a scan button, which takes to the scanning mode on clicking it. On each scanning it returns a value and again i need to click the scan button for the next scan.
Instead my requirement is I need to keep scanning the barcodes unless user clicks a cancel button in the camera preview. 


I don't know how to achieve this. 

Is it possible to add a custom barcode scanner in my phonegap application instead using the plugin.
Please help.

Regards,
Saru

Comment: we not code monkey. please state what you already achieved so far.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that the barcode scanner plugin works fine in my phonegap project.I am in this stage only. I havent tried any thing and  i just want to know whether it is possible to add a button over the camera preview of my plugin in cardova android.

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?